# How do I add skeleton text to new vim files?

Tags: vimrc, buffers, autocmd, filetype-c++

I use Vim for writing C++, and I have quite a few `#include<>` statements, comments, etc. that I must include in each new file I create.  I've added

```
autocmd BufNewFile *.cpp r C:\(full file path of skeleton text file)
```

to my vimrc, because I heard this creates a buffer with the text I need in it.  How do I go about adding this text to a new file?  Is there an easy way to do this from the buffer, or is there another easy way to go about doing this?  I've also heard a little about template plugins. Is there a very simple one that could do this for me?

Comment: Did you try out editing a new C++ file after adding this `autocmd`, and creating the skeleton file?

Comment: I tried creating a new file with a .cpp file extension and editing it with Vim.  Upon opening it for editing, it was still blank is there another step I need to do?

Comment: No, you should have seen the contents of the skeleton file already included. What if you manually run `:r  C:\(full file path of skeleton text file)`? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Just go clarify, did you create a .cpp file, then edit it in vim, or did you do an action such as `:e newfile.cpp`?

Comment: @fruglemonkey I used :enew then :sav filename.cpp.  Not sure if this is the best way to create a new file, I will try :e newfile.cpp as well.

Comment: @muru, manually running the command you mentioned does the trick, I'm not sure why that's not working from my vimrc.  Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: @electriccello Ah, `:enew` won't work, but `:e newfile.cpp` should work if `newfile.cpp` didn't already exist (even if empty).

Comment: Bingo that did it! Thanks so much for the solution I spent way too much time trying to figure that out on my own!

Comment: What did it? You can post what worked as an answer.

Comment: The reason `:enew` wont work is because you're editing a new, unnamed buffer, and *then* saving it as a .cpp file. `BufNewFile` only triggers if you're editing a new file with the target filename.

Comment: That makes sense, I just didn't know the difference between :enew and :e filename.

Answer (score 7):

Skeleton text from an existing file can be added to a new file by inserting the line

```
autocmd BufNewFile *.cpp r C:\(full file path of skeleton text file)
```

into the vimrc. The `BufNewFile` event does not work if the new file is created in two steps using `:enew` then `:sav filename`. Instead, creating a new file using `:e filename` triggers the `BufNewFile` event's autocommand in the vimrc, adding the contents of the skeleton text file to the newly created file.

Comment: Also see  [`:help template`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#template).

Comment: To prevent my `.vimrc` from being congested, is there any other location in the `~/.vim/` hierarchy I can put it into?

Comment: This also adds an additional blank line on the top in the new file.

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, template expander plugins will help you in this task. `:read` is the step 0 of template expander plugins.

For instance, [mu-template](https://github.com/LucHermitte/mu-template) will try to include foo.h from foo.cpp if foo.h is detected. It'll also permit to expand headers with dynamic data within them (date, author, license/copyright, etc).

Answer (score 1):

To setup default skeleton for all filetypes and customize it for specific project:

```
function! s:load_skeleton(type)
  " do nothing if no filetype
  if empty(a:type) | return | endif

  " glob every directory of rtp to search for skeleton/filetype
  let skeletons = globpath(&rtp, 'skeleton/' . a:type, 0, 1)
  if empty(skeletons) | return | endif

  " read last skeleton into 1st line.
  exe '0read ' . skeletons[-1]
endfunction

augroup aug_skeleton
  au!

  " BufNewFile event is trigged when you edit a new file.
  autocmd BufNewFile * call s:load_skeleton(&filetype)
augroup end
```

Put default skeletons under `~/.vim/skeleton`, eg: `~/.vim/skeleton/vim`, `~/.vim/skeleton/sh`.

Put project specific skeleton under `balabala/project/.vim/skeleton`. As long as `~/.vim` appears  before  `balabala/project/.vim` in `:h rtp`, `balabala/project/skeleton/` will be used as skeleton directory.

Comment: What's the reason for the first two lines of the `augroup`?