# Is it possible to add a specific text string in the beginning of creating a certain file type?

Tags: vimrc, filetype, filetype-python

Just like the topic says; is it possible to add a certain text string in the beginning of a file if I create a certain file type?

For example, if I create a random Python file with `vim random.py`. Can I configure my vim to automatically add `#!/usr/bin/python` at line 1?

I have a standard vim installation without any plugins or anything, I didn't even have a .vimrc in my /home so I manually created it. As you might have imagined by now, I am very new to using vim so my apologies if this is a dumb question.

I found [How do I add skeleton text to new vim files?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6358/how-do-i-add-skeleton-text-to-new-vim-files) but I am not sure if that is what I am looking for, or how to do it. If it turns out that this question is a duplicate of the question linked, I will try to look it up furthermore once I get home from work.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Thanks for all the answers and I am sorry that this question indeed was a duplicate.

Comment: You question is indeed a close duplicate of the other one. Either you do it by hand as suggested by the other post and by vim documentation, or you use one of the numerous [template expander plugin](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Automated_Text_Insertion). And instead of `:r`, you have `:put=` and many more alternatives if you don't want to maintain template-files

Comment: You might also want to look at the various snippet solutions such as [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish it by placing

```
autocmd BufNewFile *.py norm i#!/usr/bin/python
```

in your `.vimrc` file.  This should insert the text at the beginning of the first file, whenever you open a non-existing file with the file extension `py`.

The part `norm i#!/usr/bin/python` is simply commands which are executed when the file is opened.  As it is a new file, the cursor vil automatically be on the first line, which is empty.  Then `norm` treats the rest of the commands as you where in normal mode, which means that `i` takes you to insert mode and, when in insert mode `#!/usr/bin/python` simply types these characters.

Comment: Since all of the answers seems to work and are very similar I marked your answer out of sympathy reputaion-wise :)

Comment: @127.0.0.1: Well, thanks.  The points can sometimes be difficult to come by :)

Answer (score 3):

Yup the question you linked should have helped you:

```
autocmd BufNewFile *.py normal! ggI#!/bin/python
```

In your vimrc will create an autocomd which will trigger when you create a new file `BufNewFile` of the filetype python `*.py`.

When It is trigger it will go to the first line of the file `gg`, start insert mode `I` and add the shebang line

---

**Edit**

As the autocommand triggers on `BufNewFile` the file is empty since it has just been created, the `gg` is not necessary. Also using `i` instead of `I` will not change anything as the line is empty.

Comment: you do not need `gg` as `BufNewFile` only applies to non-existing files (see `:help BufNewFile`).  If you where to use `BufNew`,, then it would apply to all `.py` files.

Comment: @Kristian Yup that's what my edit said :-)

Comment: @statox:  Ahh, sorry :)  I misunderstood your edit then.  I thought what you where saying was that, if the file is empty, it is not necessary, rather than it is always empty.  By the way, my comment on `BufNew` was wrong.  It does not just work on all `.py` files.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following autocommand

```
autocmd BufNewFile *.py call append(0,'#!/bin/python')
```

Have a look at `:h append()`