# auto insert text when creating a new file

Tags: autocompletion, snippets

Is there a way to auto insert text in vim when a new file is created? Maybe there is a plugin for it? Here is what I'm talking about:

I work a lot with C/C++ and Python. Very often I need to create .h and .py files. We have some coding standards ( duh ). For example every .h file needs to have a following code:

```
#ifndef _filename
#define _filename

#endif // _filename
```

and every python file needs to have the following:

```
if '__main__' == __name__:
    main()
```

Is there a plugin that will auto insert this type of code automatically when the file is created? I know there are snippets out there, but I would prefer for it to be done automatically without engaging them?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this will work for you: https://github.com/aperezdc/vim-template

Comment: Search for `vim template` at wikia, e.g.: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Use_eval_to_create_dynamic_templates

Comment: Mostly a dupe of http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/6358/205

Answer (score 4):

As multiple people have said in various comments, check out `:h skeleton`. This sounds like just what your looking for. However if you want a little more customizability you can try the following...

Detecting when a file is "created" might be hard, since vim creates files by writing buffers to files. But you can detect when you write to a file with the `BufWritePre` autocmd.

Edit

Another possible solution would be to use the `BufNewfile` autocmd. You can substitute either in the code below to find out what works best for you.

/Edit

You could call a function to insert the text. Something like:

```
autocmd BufNewFile *.h  :call CheckHFile()
autocmd BufNewFile *.py :call CheckPyFile()

function! CheckHFile()
   let filename = expand("%:t")
   if (getline("1") !~ '#ifndef _'.filename)
      exe "normal!ggO#ifndef _".filename
      exe "normal!o#define _".filename
      exe "normal!o^M#endif // _".filename
   endif
endfunction

function! CheckPyFile()
   if (getline("1") !~ "if '__main__' == __name__:")
      normal!ggOif '__main__' == __name__:
      normal!o    main()
   endif
endfunction
```

This will make sure that these lines exist in the file before writing.

- `expand("%:t")` retrieves the file name to be used in the template.
- Note that `^M` will need to be re-typed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>

See

```
:h autocmd
:h expand
```

for more info.

Comment: `BufNewFile` might be one way :)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that one existed. Good find. I'll update.

Comment: To be fair most python coders add the `if __main__ ...` at the end of the file not the beginning.  Adding one or two empty lines above that would be useful.

Comment: Also `:h skeleton` or `:h template`

Comment: @grochmal `getline('$')` would work for that. But I'm going to wait to see if OP says anything before updating that.